# Did I convert this decimal correctly into fixed-point arithmetic?

Tags: arithmetic, binary

This was asked in the exam I have written today and confused me, I'd like to know if I did it correctly:

> Convert the decimal $9.5$ to fixed-point arithmetic, with $5$ significant figures.

I took $9$ and converted it to binary first: $1001$

Now I took the significant figure $0.5$ and multiplied it with $2$:

$$0.5 \cdot 2 = 1.0$$

$$0 \cdot 2 = 0.0$$

$$0 \cdot 2 = 0$$

$$0 \cdot 2 = 0$$

$\Rightarrow$ $9.5$ in fixed-point arithmetic is $1001\ 10000$

Please tell me if it's correct, I did it exactly like this in the exam and I hope it's right because the exam was hard and this was one of the easy task but the zeroes made me feel unsure : /

Comment: It seems fine. The number should be $1001.1$ written in binary.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, the correct answer is $1001.1$ (which has five significant figures) and *not* $1001.10000$ (which has nine significant figures).